# Search techniques for a bot in a field

Tags: artificial-intelligence, bots

My field consists of open grid spaces and filled grid spaces. My bot can move on only open spaces. It can only detect if there is a filled grid space in any of its 8 neighbouring grids (i.e. up, down, left, right , and diagnol spaces). That is, it cannot look beyond the 8 neighbouring spaces. What would be the best search technique in such a grid? My aim, lets say, is to find the no of objects in the grid ( an object is a connected set of filled spaces)

I've tried the following, all have been pretty bad:

1. keeping a list of spaces visited ( by taking initial position as 0,0 and storing relative positions of the spaces visited). That is, I preferably visit those locations which have not been visited.
2. Initially go to the bottommost and leftmost point, then start searching exhaustively for 5 bottom rows, then the next 5 bottom rows, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your aim, but the most common (non-optimized) algorithm for general grid path-finding, grid flood-fill, etc. is A* (pronounced "A - Star"). Its most widespread application is grid-based path-finding with "open" and "closed" nodes; much like your "open" and "filled" grid spaces.

Check out
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! However, when using A*, I require the whole graph beforehand. Here, I can only look in the 8 neighbouring positions, I don't really have information about the whole grid. Maybe I should first traverse through the entire grid, to find out the open and filled spaces, and then use A* to go to the objects?

Answer (score 0):

You don't describe why you consider your solutions "pretty bad", but I assume you observe inefficient search behavior. An attempt you might want to try is to label each space with "value of information" that is, how many previously undiscovered neighboring spaces will you discover when you would visit that space. This is your "reward". Your "cost" is the distance to travel to that particular space. Then you will have to find a devise a search strategy that maximizes (reward - cost).

Comment: Initially I am at (1,1). One strategy that seems really simple,  but every way I look at it, it seems a good strategy, is that I keep going right, till the end of the grid, then move one space up and keep going left till the end, then again one space up ... Its a really naive strategy but seems too simple.. is there a catch to this strategy? I am confused whether to implement this one or the cost-reward model one.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a *partially observable markov decision process*. Maybe have a look at *reinforcement learning*. There's a f[ree online version](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/ebook/the-book.html) of a book by Sutton and Barto.

I think the problem is too hard for reinforcement learning producing a good result and it is too uncertain for classical approaches (using logic).